# pyenv set local python for a project

Tags: pyenv

I can't seem to be able to set local python for a project, not even global python.

```
$ pyenv local 3.9.6
$ pyenv global 3.9.6

$ pyenv versions
system
* 3.9.6 (set by /home/cmap/c-map/.python-version)
```

In .python-version it is written 3.9.6
But when I type python -V I get 3.7.3 which is the original system installed python
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found what was missing. Had to add the following to .profile

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
```